# How do I get rid of unused views on CouchDB using futon?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Basically what the question says.

I have a database where I've created a bunch of different views while trying to learn how the whole thing works.  Now I have a few views I really need and a lot of views I don't need.  However I have not been able to find a way to remove those views using futon.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm also accepting solutions that don't involve futon.

Comment: I just feel like I'm missing something really obvious.  Looking in google for 'delete couchDB view' doesn't return anything.  I hate missing really obvious things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views map/reduce code is located inside design docs. You have to remove the view from the ddoc which you can achive via futon

```
DB > design docs > ddoc > remove view code > save ddoc
```

In which ddoc a particular view is stored can be seen in the filter dropdown in futon.

Alternatively the ddoc update can be done via CouchDB API.